# Understanding two pieces of code which fetch memory locations

Tags: c, memory-address, bootloader

I have the task of building a bootloader which has been successful but lead to the all important question in why it worked. Working through it, I am stumped on two very similar lines of code.

```
    //Get the application stack pointer (1st entry in the application vector table)
    appStack = (uint32_t) *((__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS);

    //Get the application entry address (2nd entry in the application entry table)
    appEntry = (pFunction) *(__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4);
```

I have defined `APPLICATION_ADDRESS`. I have defined `pFunction` to be a pointer to a function. This is my understanding attempt:

(ignoring `__IO` as this is just meaning `volatile`)

`(__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS)` casts `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` to be a pointer which returns a 32-bit unsigned integer. This means if we go to address `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` there will be another address of a memory location holding a `uint32_t`.

In `*((__IO uint32_t *) APPLICATION_ADDRESS)` we use the dereference operator to gain the value the `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` is pointing to. The `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` points to another address which holds a value which will be returned. The `(uint32_t)` then casts this value to be `uint32_t`.

Following my line of understanding renders the casting redundant as you have already said the variable held is `uint32_t` within the brackets.

This then contradicts my understanding of the next line. Why haven't we defined `APP_ADDRESS + 4` to be a `pFunction` within the brackets initially?

Finally I am confused with the difference in brackets arrangements. Why does the dereference operator not surround the whole `int_32` and `(APPLICATION_ADDRESS +4)` like so:

`*((__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4))`

or is this overkill with brackets and it is just not required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few correct assumptions and a few wrong assumptions.

You seem to have 2 values stored at a fixed location within your memory:

```
APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 0  +----------------------+
                         |     Stack            |
                    + 4  +----------------------+
                         |     pFunction        |
                    + 8  +----------------------+
```

Now lets look at your assumptions:

> `(__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS)` casts `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` to be
>   a pointer which returns a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Yes, correct.

> This means if we go to address `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` there will be another
>   address of a memory location holding a uint32_t.

Close but not true.

At the location `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` you do not find another address to an integer, but there you find said integer itself.

> In *((__IO uint32_t *) APPLICATION_ADDRESS) we use the dereference
>   operator to gain the value the `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` is pointing to.

Yes.
Well, to be a bit pedantic, `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` does not point anywhere. It is just a plain number, not a pointer. That's the reason why you need to do all the casts to various pointer types.

> The `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` points to another address which holds a value
>   which will be returned. The `(uint32_t)` then casts this value to be
>   `uint32_t`.

No, `APPLICATION_ADDRESS` **IS** the address of that integer.

> Following my line of understanding renders the casting redundant as
>   you have already said the variable held is uint32_t within the
>   brackets.

Correct.

> This then contradicts my understanding of the next line. Why haven't
>   we defined `APP_ADDRESS + 4` to be a pFunction within the brackets
>   initially?

Casting from integer to pointers is implementation dependent. Even more for function addresses. If the memory content is defined to be 32 bit integer, you must read it with that type. Then you can do any conversion if required.
This might just result in same value or it might differ. That depends on the architecture.

> Finally I am confused with the difference in brackets arrangements.
>   Why does the dereference operator not surround the whole `int_32` and
>   `(APPLICATION_ADDRESS +4)` like so:
>
> ```
> *((__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4))
> ```
>
> or is this overkill with brackets and it is just not required?

The outer brackets are not required.
The inner brackets are important. Without the brackets the cast would have higher precedence over the addition. Then you would not add 4 bytes to the address but the size of 4 memory objects which would be 16 bytes here.

Comment: Many Thanks for your Help! Much appreciated.